# write_csv() produces bank cells in msexcel

Tags: r, csv, save

This isn't a major issue, but I still thought I would ask.

I've been cleaning some data for a project at work, and there's a point at the process where I save all of the individual files I've cleaned as a CSV in long format.  I noticed that with some of the files that if I open them, some cells that SHOULD have data appear blank.  If I use the "Clear All Formats" option, the data appears.  It reads into R just fine and it hasn't caused any issues, but I still think it's weird.

Has anyone else run into this and if so, was there a way to resolve this without going through each column?  The files I'm cleaning start out with all sorts of formatting, so I'm curious if that could be the cause.  I thought that a CSV doesn't save formats though, so I'm a little confused.

Again, not the biggest deal but slightly annoying and I'll get questions about it if my colleagues ever take a look at these files.

The data is prorietary, and I'm not exactly sure how I would share it. but I'm using a pretty stragith forward `write_csv(data,"path.csv")`

Comment: Do some values contain a carriage return?

Comment: Have you tried using write.csv() with the readr package?

Comment: You can share data using `dput()`. We don't need much, just a a couple rows and columns that exhibit the problem, e.g., `dput(your_data[10:11, c(3, 5)])` for rows 10 and 11, columns 3 and 5. You could also share faked data that behaves similarly.

Comment: @FruityPebblePug I think you've got things backwards - OP mentions `write_csv` which is in the `readr` package. Your rec, `write.csv`, is the built-in function.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I'm actually not sure how to reproduce the issue, because it seems to be happening randomly.  It could just be an internal issue with my computer.  Just thought I'd ask to see if someone else had seen this before!

Comment: No - that sounds weird. I don't think we can help unless you provide more information - even just the `dput()` of one or two cells that show the issue.

Comment: I understand.  Boss gave me a hard no on that.  I'll play with it a bit more and see if I can reproduce something with some fake data.  Thank you for getting back to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the solution to this issue, and I wanted to share in case anyone else runs into this.

I'm using a Windows Computer, which needed an update.  That got me thinking and I needed to update my version of RStudio.  I'm not sure what would have caused this issue, but when I re-run those files, the issue appears to be resolved.